# Not able to connect to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysqli, phpmyadmin, lamp, ubuntu-18.04

I am not able to connect to phpmyadmin from browser.
I can connect to mysql from terminal.
when i try to login to phpmyadmin it is showing following error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason for this is a difference in connection type. phpMyAdmin defaults to using the hostname 'localhost' (which implies a socket connection). Depending how your various connections are configured (if you've changed the host in phpMyAdmin or how your command line client is connecting) it could easily be a difference in the host field of the defined user.

To MySQL, a user has to authenticate not only based on username and password, but the host field as well. A user can be defined with a host `%` which is a wildcard matching any host over TCP/IP networking. It does not match a socket connection. A socket connection must match the host 'localhost'.

You can either create another user that's identical but change the host field, or change the connection type for phpMyAdmin to match whatever the command line client is using. At the command line client, run the `STATUS;` command and look at the "Connection" line to see how that's connecting (and also the "Current user", perhaps), then you can configure phpMyAdmin to match that connection type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but this issue got resolved. i changed so many things so i don't remember what did the trick.